# Posting to main looper, order of execution

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask

I have an asyncTask that is updating some data in a background thread. When I need to update my UI, I post to the main thread using the following:

```
Handler mainHandler = new Handler(context.getMainLooper());
mainHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
                //do stuff on main thread
        }
    }
);
```

I'm wondering, is there any guaranty about the order that the main looper will process its messages? ie: will the main thread run the the looper messages in the order that they were posted?

Also, if I post to the main thread using the code above in my AsyncTask's `doInBackground` method, will these be run before the AsyncTask's `onPostExecute` method is run?

Comment: why aren't you using `publishProgress()` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The things posted on a looper through a handler will execute in the order you posted them.

The things you post in doInBackground will be posted before the things you post in onPostExecute.

Keep in mind that onPostExecute runs on the main looper already.

Consider using onProgressUpdate instead of posting on a handler, it will be called on the main looper when you do publishProgress from your doInBackground method.